# git deleted all my files. How do I restore them?

Tags: git

I started using git yesterday and I managed to lost all my files. Since then I've done a lot of searching but still wasn't able to recover them. However, when I do:
`$git show <content on .git/REBASE_HEAD>` I notice all my files are there.
Also, `$git status` says: **rebase in progress; onto 6ad34aa**.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried `git rebase --abort`?

Comment: (btw, `$` isn't part of the command)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Git can not delete files, unless you give it a command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your git repo rebase is in progress.

Try to abort rebasing and return initial state

```
git rebase --abort
```